# Why is 'Inset Faces' insetting faces individually?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I'm following tutorial on Youtube. Why can't I inset selected faces like this guy does?

[image]

Instead it insets faces individually:

[image]

I did exactly what the tutorial said, I also use the same user preference settings but still this problem arises.

I tried to use *Remove doubles* in a round torso but the result is different:

[image]

I don't use *Individually Inset Faces* and this isn't the first time, I had the same problem while making the shoulder but managed to fix it somehow.

He uses *Extrude* first then *Scale* in the process while somehow I can't use that way and end up using *Inset Faces* instead.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The faces are being inset into two regions because *Inset* isn't taking into account the *Mirror* modifier.

Make sure you don't have any more doubles, and immediately after pressing <kbd>I</kbd> to start insetting, press <kbd>B</kbd> to enable the "boundary" option.